# my migrations are being saved in another project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, rake

Recently I was working on a rails project and I asked for some help from someone else. This other person messed up my Gemfile.lock and they ended up just making a copy of my project and renaming the original folder to `original_project`.

Everything else works fine and I've been developing and pushing to github on this new version of my project. But now anytime I run `rake db:migrate`, it saves the migration to the `original_project` folder. Even though the migration is being run from the new project folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Will this have any other effect on my database when I try to deploy?

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Ive discovered that none of my rails commands are working. Anytime I generate any model or controller or anything, it's being saved to that original project folder. This is really frustrating... Does anyone have any ideas whats going on?

Comment: try removing/moving the old project files and post your errors.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the confusion. The `rake` tasks were working just fine. I think that all the `rails` commands were tied to my original project folder and when the other developer tried to copy the original folder into a new one, the rails commands were still being comprehended by the original folder.

So I ended up spending some time to fix the broken Gemfile.lock issue, pulled all my updated work from github back into the original project folder and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that `rake db:migrate` updates the schema in the original folder?. Try `rake db:reset` That will drop, create and send migrations to a new database. I don't think this has anything to do with your Gemfile.lock. I don't think you'll have problems when you deploy as long as your schema is configured. The database in production starts new. Here is a good link to [rake db:tasks](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/02/all-rails-db-rake-tasks-and-what-they-do.html).